# Is there a more concise way to rewrite that F# function?

Tags: f#

Here is a function that converts a number to a string with the requested precision and a leading sign:

```
let formatValueSign (precision: decimal) (value: decimal) =
    let precisionString =
        match precision with
        | 0.1m      -> "{0:+#.0;-#.0; 0.0}"
        | 0.01m     -> "{0:+#.00;-#.00; 0.00}"
        | 0.001m    -> "{0:+#.000;-#.000; 0.000}"
        | 0.0001m   -> "{0:+#.0000;-#.0000; 0.0000}"
        | 0.00001m  -> "{0:+#.00000;-#.00000; 0.00000}"
        | 0.000001m -> "{0:+#.000000;-#.000000; 0.000000}"
        | _         -> "{0:+#0;-#0;0}"

    String.Format(precisionString, value)
```

The expected output has the sign in front of the number and the precision is represented by a decimal number, but it can also be passed as *i* where the precision is *pown 0.1m i* if it's more convenient.

Is there a way to make this more concise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could calculate the number of zeros in the format string using `log10` and then generate the format string dynamically. The following does not correctly handle corner cases, but it works for the cases in the middle of your range:

```
let formatValueSign (precision: decimal) (value: decimal) =
  let places = int (log10 (float (1.0m/precision)))
  let zeros = String.replicate places "0"
  let precisionString = sprintf "{0:+#.%s;-#.%s; 0.%s}" zeros zeros zeros
  String.Format(precisionString, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want correctly, I think something like this does essentially the same thing:

```
(Decimal.Round(value / precision) * precision).ToString()
```

And it also handles precision > 1, such as:

```
formatValueSign 100m -12345.6789m -> "-12300"
```

You can tweak the `ToString()` part to generate the leading `+` sign if you want. Personally, I would break this into two functions, though: One to generate a decimal with the correct precision, and a separate one that formats it to your liking.

Last thought: I would probably define the precision as an integer exponent (e.g. `-2` instead of `0.01m`), because the current signature accepts precisions that aren't powers of 10. Better to make invalid values unrepresentable IMHO.

Comment: I picked Tomas' answer because it matches the required output out of the box. But regarding the precision, you are right using the number of digits makes more sense than having a decimal number representing.